# How to join two tables when there's no coincidence?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables that I want to join. I've tried an usual left and right join but neither gives the result I want.

**TABLE A**

```
ID_A     VALUE_A
-----------------
A           1     
B           2
```

**TABLE B**

```
ID_B   ID_A    VALUE_B
-------------------------
90       A        1
90       C        1
90       E        1  
91       A        1
91       B        1
92       B        1
92       E        1
92       F        1
```

I want to get this result:

```
ID_A   VALUE_A     ID_B     ID_A   VALUE_B 
-------------------------------------------------
A        1          90        A       1 
B        2          90        NULL    NULL 
A        1          91        A       1 
B        2          91        B       1
A        1          92        NULL    NULL
B        2          92        B       1
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your result?

Comment: "when there's no coincidence" is not a clear description of however it is you want output to be a function of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all combinations of `id_a` and `value_a` from the first table along with all distinct `id_b` from the second table.  If so:

```
select iv.id_a, iv.value_a, ib.id_b, b.id_a, b.value_b
from (select distinct id_a, value_a from a) iv cross join
     (select distinct id_b from b) ib left join
     b
     on b.id_b = ib.id_b and b.id_a = iv.id_a;
```

The `cross join` generates the rows.  The `left join` brings in the additional columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works pretty well. But, how can I do to not select 
the rows grouped by `ib.id_b` when all of them are NULL.

Comment: @cthulhu . . . I'm not sure I understand.  Can you ask another question with appropriate data?

Comment: I already solved the issue I had. Your answer was so much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.ID_A , A.VALUE_A , B.ID_B , B.ID_A , B.VALUE_B
  FROM            TABLE_A A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B B
   ON A.ID_A = B.ID_A ;
```

**EDIT**: Typos corrected following sticky bit note (thanks!!).

Comment: It's `LEFT OUTER JOIN` not `OUTER LEFT_JOIN`. And here `A.IDA_A , A.VALURE_A` there are some typos I guess.

Comment: Thank you @stickybit, you are of course correct twice (your correction and my typos).

Answer (score 1):

I usually break things like this down into CTEs:

### DDL

```
use tempdb

CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID_A] varchar(1), [VALUE_A] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID_A], [VALUE_A])
VALUES
    ('A', 1),
    ('B', 2)
;


CREATE TABLE Table2
    ([ID_B] int, [ID_A] varchar(1), [VALUE_B] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table2
    ([ID_B], [ID_A], [VALUE_B])
VALUES
    (90, 'A', 1),
    (90, 'C', 1),
    (90, 'E', 1),
    (91, 'A', 1),
    (91, 'B', 1),
    (92, 'B', 1),
    (92, 'E', 1),
    (92, 'F', 1)
;
```

---

### Answer

```
with a as (
        select distinct id_b
        from Table2
),
b as (
        select  id_a, value_a, id_b
        from    Table1 cross join a
)
select  b.id_a, b.value_a, b.id_b, t2.id_a, t2.value_b
from    b left join Table2 t2
        on b.id_a = t2.id_a
        and b.id_b = t2.id_b
```

---

### Results

```
+------+---------+------+------+---------+
| id_a | value_a | id_b | id_a | value_b |
+------+---------+------+------+---------+
| A    |       1 |   90 | A    | 1       |
| B    |       2 |   90 | NULL | NULL    |
| A    |       1 |   91 | A    | 1       |
| B    |       2 |   91 | B    | 1       |
| A    |       1 |   92 | NULL | NULL    |
| B    |       2 |   92 | B    | 1       |
+------+---------+------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resolve the exact logic and couldn't match the results exactly as desired , but presume you'd like to get something like :

```
SELECT a.ID_A, COALESCE(a.VALUE_A,b.VALUE_B) VALUE_A, b.ID_B, a.ID_A, 
       (CASE WHEN a.ID_A IS NULL THEN a.ID_A ELSE CAST(b.VALUE_B as VARCHAR(1)) END) 
       as VALUE_B
  FROM TABLE_A a FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b 
  ON ( a.ID_A = b.ID_A )
 GROUP BY a.ID_A, a.VALUE_A, b.ID_B, a.ID_A, b.VALUE_B 
 ORDER BY 3, 2, 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/32043/38)